# Should I use getState directly from store in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an application created with react and redux, when application starts, i fetched some data from API (configuration, for example user statuses and it's labels to show, some kind of dictionary for internationalization),

I have view with users list, and every row of list is instance of `User` class, i want to show, users status in human readable way, so I need statuses fetched from API,

I use redux and redux-thunk to get dictionaries from API and store dictionaries in redux store,

I want to create method in User class to return status as human readable string, so I can send status dictionary with props to `ListComponent` and send it as parametr to `User.getStatus` method (method can return `dict[this.status])` but i don't think it is good way, so in module with User class declaration i import my redux store (result of `combineReducers`) and in `getStatus` method i call `store.getState()` and get status dictionary from returned value, it is a good practice or i can do it better?

Comment: i'm not sure if I get it correctly but maybe just familiarize Yourself with mapStateToProps() function instead od getting state directly from stroe

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing a low-level api of redux that is only meant for library authors. You should be using the `react-redux` package which has a Higher-Order Component called `connect` which you can use to subscribe to your store. As @Michal Cholewiński mentioned, you can use the `mapStateToProps` function to pass your reducer state into your component as a prop.

The Redux authors made a great tutorial showing [how you should integrate with react.](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react)

Comment: ok i get it but i don't want pass my state to component, i know what do this, i need get value from my store in class which is not a component but something like model to store data about user in nice format

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer you pass the data as a parameter to make the user class reusable, meaning it can work on it's own even without access to the store.  Otherwise it's ok to access the state from the store as well. To keep things modular you can try [redux-named-reducers](https://github.com/mileschristian/redux-named-reducers) which let's you access the latest state from reducers like so, from anywhere in your code:

```
state1 = getState(reducerA.state1)
```